# Javascript , Geojson, Json

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapping

I am trying to build a map, i did all the data in GIS (QGIS,ESRI) i am trying to publish it using leaflet , my problem is , i have a json will be for the updated data like cases numbers , and i want it to reflect in info bar, update,
so when user hover over the country , it will get the name or code from geojson properties by oneachfeature and try to find it in the json, then return multi results from the json array i choose.
I tried to filter and looping through , for json to json it works , i don't know why it faild for geojson to json
Am Looking for Suggestion .
Here Example for json file:

```
    var copy =[
{"type":"header","version":"4.9.0.1","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
{"type":"database","name":"corona"},
{"type":"table","name":"scrap1","database":"corona","data":[
{"id":"23","Country_Other":"S. Korea","Total_Cases":"10,423","New_Cases":"+39","Total_Deaths":"204 ","New_Deaths":"+4","Total_Recovered":"6,973","Active_Cases":"3,246","Serious_Critical":"55","TotCases_1Mpop":"203","Deaths_1Mpop":"4","Total_Tests":"477,304","Tests_1Mpop":"9,310"},
{"id":"24","Country_Other":"Russia","Total_Cases":"10,131","New_Cases":"+1,459","Total_Deaths":"76 ","New_Deaths":"+13","Total_Recovered":"698","Active_Cases":"9,357","Serious_Critical":"8","TotCases_1Mpop":"69","Deaths_1Mpop":"0.5","Total_Tests":"1,004,719","Tests_1Mpop":"6,885"},
{"id":"25","Country_Other":"Israel","Total_Cases":"9,968","New_Cases":"+564","Total_Deaths":"86 ","New_Deaths":"+13","Total_Recovered":"1,011","Active_Cases":"8,871","Serious_Critical":"166","TotCases_1Mpop":"1,152","Deaths_1Mpop":"10","Total_Tests":"117,339","Tests_1Mpop":"13,557"},
{"id":"26","Country_Other":"Sweden","Total_Cases":"9,141","New_Cases":"+722","Total_Deaths":"793 ","New_Deaths":"+106","Total_Recovered":"205","Active_Cases":"8,143","Serious_Critical":"719","TotCases_1Mpop":"905","Deaths_1Mpop":"79","Total_Tests":"54,700","Tests_1Mpop":"5,416"},
{"id":"27","Country_Other":"India","Total_Cases":"6,725","New_Cases":"+809","Total_Deaths":"226 ","New_Deaths":"+48","Total_Recovered":"620","Active_Cases":"5,879","Serious_Critical":"","TotCases_1Mpop":"5","Deaths_1Mpop":"0.2","Total_Tests":"177,584","Tests_1Mpop":"129"},
{"id":"9","Country_Other":"Spain","Total_Cases":"152,446","New_Cases":"+4,226","Total_Deaths":"15,238 ","New_Deaths":"+446","Total_Recovered":"52,165","Active_Cases":"85,043","Serious_Critical":"7,371","TotCases_1Mpop":"3,261","Deaths_1Mpop":"326","Total_Tests":"355,000","Tests_1Mpop":"7,593"},
{"id":"10","Country_Other":"Italy","Total_Cases":"143,626","New_Cases":"+4,204","Total_Deaths":"18,279 ","New_Deaths":"+610","Total_Recovered":"28,470","Active_Cases":"96,877","Serious_Critical":"3,605","TotCases_1Mpop":"2,375","Deaths_1Mpop":"302","Total_Tests":"853,369","Tests_1Mpop":"14,114"},
{"id":"11","Country_Other":"France","Total_Cases":"117,749","New_Cases":"+4,799","Total_Deaths":"12,210 ","New_Deaths":"+1,341","Total_Recovered":"23,206","Active_Cases":"82,333","Serious_Critical":"7,066","TotCases_1Mpop":"1,804","Deaths_1Mpop":"187","Total_Tests":"333,807","Tests_1Mpop":"5,114"}
]
}
]
```

Example for the GEOJson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "newcount",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FID_1": 53, "featurecla": "Admin-0 country", "scalerank": 4, "LABELRANK": 2, "SOVEREIGNT": "Spain", "SOV_A3": "ESP", "ADM0_DIF": 0, "LEVEL": 2, "TYPE": "Sovereign country", "ADMIN": "Spain", "ADM0_A3": "ESP", "GEOU_DIF": 0, "GEOUNIT": "Spain", "GU_A3": "ESP", "SU_DIF": 0, "SUBUNIT": "Spain", "SU_A3": "ESP", "BRK_DIFF": 0, "NAME": "Spain", "NAME_LONG": "Spain", "BRK_A3": "ESP", "BRK_NAME": "Spain", "BRK_GROUP": null, "ABBREV": "Sp.", "POSTAL": "E", "FORMAL_EN": "Kingdom of Spain", "FORMAL_FR": null, "NAME_CIAWF": "Spain", "NOTE_ADM0": null, "NOTE_BRK": null, "NAME_SORT": "Spain", "NAME_ALT": null, "MAPCOLOR7": 4, "MAPCOLOR8": 5, "MAPCOLOR9": 5, "MAPCOLOR13": 5, "POP_EST": 48958159, "POP_RANK": 15, "GDP_MD_EST": 1690000.0, "POP_YEAR": 2017, "LASTCENSUS": 2001, "GDP_YEAR": 2016, "ECONOMY": "2. Developed region: nonG7", "INCOME_GRP": "1. High income: OECD", "WIKIPEDIA": -99, "FIPS_10_": "SP", "ISO_A2": "ES", "ISO_A3": "ESP", "ISO_A3_EH": "ESP", "ISO_N3": "724", "UN_A3": "724", "WB_A2": "ES", "WB_A3": "ESP", "WOE_ID": 23424950, "WOE_ID_EH": 23424950, "WOE_NOTE": "Exact WOE match as country", "ADM0_A3_IS": "ESP", "ADM0_A3_US": "ESP", "ADM0_A3_UN": -99, "ADM0_A3_WB": -99, "CONTINENT": "Europe", "REGION_UN": "Europe", "SUBREGION": "Southern Europe", "REGION_WB": "Europe & Central Asia", "NAME_LEN": 5, "LONG_LEN": 5, "ABBREV_LEN": 3, "TINY": -99, "HOMEPART": 1, "MIN_ZOOM": 0.0, "MIN_LABEL": 2.0, "MAX_LABEL": 7.0, "NE_ID": 1159320587, "WIKIDATAID": "Q29", "NAME_AR": "إسبانيا", "NAME_BN": "স্পেন", "NAME_DE": "Spanien", "NAME_EN": "Spain", "NAME_ES": "España", "NAME_FR": "Espagne", "NAME_EL": "Ισπανία", "NAME_HI": "स्पेन", "NAME_HU": "Spanyolország", "NAME_ID": "Spanyol", "NAME_IT": "Spagna", "NAME_JA": "スペイン", "NAME_KO": "스페인", "NAME_NL": "Spanje", "NAME_PL": "Hiszpania", "NAME_PT": "Espanha", "NAME_RU": "Испания", "NAME_SV": "Spanien", "NAME_TR": "İspanya", "NAME_VI": "Tây Ban Nha", "NAME_ZH": "西班牙", "FID_2": 244, "OBJECTID": 245, "FID_": 54, "SOVEREIG_1": "Spain", "ADMIN_1": "Spain", "GEOUNIT_1": "Spain", "SUBUNIT_1": "Spain", "NAME_1": "Spain", "NAME_LON_1": "Spain", "BRK_NAME_1": "Spain", "NAME_SOR_1": "Spain", "NAME_ALT_1": null, "CONTINEN_1": "Europe", "NAME_AR_1": "إسبانيا", "NAME_EN_1": "Spain", "un_name": "Spain", "Total_Co": 4231, "Total_newC": 1266, "Total_Deat": 120, "Total_Deth": 36, "Day_last": 0, "Recover": 0, "X": -3.5633652521000001, "Y": 40.399772813600002, "Distance": 0.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":   Clipped Because to long}}}}
```

Comment: You had a typo a the end of example GEOJson, the "}}}}" should be "}}]}". It will cause the GEOJson to be decoded fail.

Comment: This is just Example,  but it working fine, I can't figure how to connect the two file , then run a filter or for loop to select

Answer (score 0):

The answer is well explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json#answercell%20post-layout--right) please read it.

If you want to get the value of the key Country_Other in your copy array you have to use:

```
copy[2].data[i].Country_Other
```

If you asign the GeoJson to a variable named "copy", you will use:

```
copy.features[i].properties.Name
```

Comment: Hello , thanks for your reply,  am already using this , but still can't use it in a loop or filter method,  so when user hover over Spain like Example,  I will select the data to show in info box from json , like if value in Json file Equal to Spain,  then show cases   recovery,  and like that .

Comment: I can show for each , there data with difference ways , also with if conditions  case , for loop , as return functions, I tried all , is working,  but I can't do if value from geojson properties equal this  show these values from json file